# Dropzonejs order of upload + Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, dropzone.js

I am using dropzonejs and Laravel to my server. I wish to get the filenames like the order of files  1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg, 4.jpg,5.jpg or i have a field name order in dataabse. i want to save the order in database

My code:

```
var baseUrl = "{{ url('/') }}";
var token = "{{ Session::getToken() }}";

Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
var myDropzone = new Dropzone(".dropzone", {
    url: baseUrl + "/upload",
    params: {
        _token: token

    }
});
Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
    paramName: "flyers",
    acceptedFiles: "image/*",
    enqueueForUpload: true,
    forceFallback: false,
    dictDefaultMessage: "Drop files here to upload",
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    uploadMultiple: false,
    maxFilesize: 2, // MB
    addRemoveLinks: true,

    accept: function(file, done) {

    },
};
```

my controller

```
public function album()
{
$file = Input::file('file');

$destinationPath = 'uploads';
$filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();

$uploadSuccsess = Input::file('file')->move($destinationPath, $filename);
if( $uploadSuccsess ) {
 return Response::json('success', 200);
} else {
 return Response::json('error', 400);
} 

 }
```

}

Comment: You mention a database, but I don't see anything in your code snippets which use a database. Please clarify.

Comment: this is a sample code only.

Comment: ok so what have you tried then? Why mention a database in your question?